# How to send & receive data from ios application with JSON

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

Hi i am not very much familiar to iOS programming , 
i am making an application that will interact with web (php).

I need to know how to send & receive the data from web using JSON ?

Comment: Vinay, This is a Q&A site. There are some site (which you can find by googling) for tutorial regarding your question. Follow them first. If you have any specific problem then, Fill free to ask it over here.

Comment: well i am searching which approach should i follow m confused in that , and i tottaly agree with your point .

Comment: Follow this one thoroughly: http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can use AFNetworking Library, In order to communicate your app with Webserver.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Read the documentation of the library and you will be get it all.